# Basic xparse does not seem to be working

Tags: macros, packages

I can't seem to get basic xparse working. This seems like a bug, but this example feels so basic that I feel that there must be something I am not understanding about how to use this.  Here is my test example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\Row{O{} O{}}{
    Token1=#1 Token2=#2\par
}

\begin{document}
    \Row{A}{B} \par
    \Row{C}    \par
    \Row       \par
\end{document}
```

The output of this is

> ```
> Token1= Token2=
> AB
> Token1= Token2=
> C
> Token1= Token2=
> ```

1. I want the empty {} values ONLY when the tokens are not provided (which is what I thought the 'O{}' meant) so not sure why I am ONLY seeing the default values for the first two cases.
2. Why are lines 2 and 3 showing up in the output? That seems as if I had actually declared

> ```
> \NewDocumentCommand\Row{O{} O{}}{
>   Token1=#1 Token2=#2\par
>   **#1#2**
> }
> ```

which is not that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\Row{O{} O{}}{
    Token1=#1 Token2=#2\par
}

\begin{document}
    \Row[A][B] \par
    \Row[C]    \par
    \Row       \par
\end{document}
```

Optional arguments are supposed to be in square brackets.

The way you had it, `\Row{A}{B}` is seen as command `\Row` with NO optional arguments, followed by the text {A}{B} which will just be typeset as AB.

Comment: Right; you need to use `g` if you want optional braced groups.

Comment: Thanks Will. I'd much prefer to use {} instead. So, why would one prefer to use O with [] instead of G with {}?

Comment: Traditionally, optional arguments in LaTeX were distinguished by square brackets as opposed to curly ones. One may want to continue doing that for consistency reasons.  It may be good to be able to see immediately whether and argument is mandatory or optional.